# Android ActivityInjector: get life cycle exception after language change

Tags: android, recreate

In my android app I have a simple language switch between 2 languages.

Everything is working fine, the language is switched well, but I noticed an error when debugging on real device, that was not there before (Xiaomi Redmi 9). It says:

***E/ActivityInjector: get life cycle exception
java.lang.ClassCastException: android.os.BinderProxy cannot be cast to android.app.servertransaction.ClientTransaction**
at android.app.ActivityInjector.checkAccessControl(ActivityInjector.java:24)
at android.app.Activity.onResume(Activity.java:1995)
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onResume(FragmentActivity.java:434)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1457)
at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:8264)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:4494)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:4536)
at android.app.servertransaction.ResumeActivityItem.execute(ResumeActivityItem.java:52)
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeLifecycleState(TransactionExecutor.java:176)
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:97)
at android.app.ClientTransactionHandler.executeTransaction(ClientTransactionHandler.java:58)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivityLocally(ActivityThread.java:5498)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$3400(ActivityThread.java:244)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2114)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:236)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7861)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:600)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:967)*

However the app doesn't crash and works well, but the error is there.

The cause might be, when I call `super.recreate()` after the language is changed to take effect and restart the MainActivity.

As I read other discussions, it might be Xiaomi related, but I have no solution how to avoid this or at least to try using something instead `recreate()`.

Here is MainActivity, you can see in `saveLang` method I am recreating the activity to reflect the new language:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        if(getSupportActionBar() != null){
            getSupportActionBar().hide();}

        SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

        if(!prefs.getBoolean("firstTime", false)) {
            String languageToLoad;
            languageToLoad = Resources.getSystem().getConfiguration().getLocales().get(0).getLanguage();

            lng = "sk".equals(languageToLoad) ? "sk" : "en";

            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
            editor.putBoolean("firstTime", true);
            editor.putString("langx", lng);
            editor.apply();

        } else {lng = readLang();}

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            updateBaseContextLocale(getBaseContext());
        }

        this.setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    }

    @Override
    protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
        super.attachBaseContext(updateBaseContextLocale(base));
    }

    private Context updateBaseContextLocale(Context context) {

        SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);

        if(!prefs.getBoolean("firstTime", false)) {
            String languageToLoad;
            languageToLoad = Resources.getSystem().getConfiguration().getLocales().get(0).getLanguage();

            if ("sk".equals(languageToLoad) || "cs".equals(languageToLoad))
            {lng = "sk";} else {lng = "en";}

            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
            editor.putBoolean("firstTime", true);
            editor.putString("langx", lng);
            editor.apply();}

        else {
            lng = prefs.getString("langx", "sk");
        }

        if(lng==null) {lng="sk";}

        Locale locale = new Locale(lng);
        Locale.setDefault(locale);

        return updateResourcesLocale(context, locale);

    }

    private Context updateResourcesLocale(Context context, Locale locale) {
        Configuration configuration = context.getResources().getConfiguration();
        configuration.setLocale(locale);
        return context.createConfigurationContext(configuration);
    }

    public void Langsk(View view)
    {
        String lng = readLang();
        String newlng;

        if (!lng.equals("sk")) {
            newlng = "sk";
            saveLang(newlng);
        }
    }

    public void Langen(View view)
    {
        String lng = readLang();
        String newlng;

        if (lng.equals("sk")) {
            newlng = "en";
            saveLang(newlng);
        }
    }

    private void saveLang(String lng) {
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        sharedPreferences.edit().putString("langx", lng).apply();

        super.recreate();
        overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
    }

    private String readLang() {
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        return sharedPreferences.getString("langx", "sk");
    }
}
```

I tried to remove `super.recreate()`, then the error is gone, but of course the language is not updated.

The only thing that helped is to use:

```
Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
        overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
        startActivity(i);
        overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
```

instead of simple `recreate()`.

With this is it working without any error, however I think this is a bit an overkill.

Comment: did u get solution ?

Comment: unfortunately not. Now my Xiaomi device has upgraded to Android 12, but the same issue persist when I use super.recreate(). So still my solution with startActivity(i) is the only way it works without any warnings. (btw. it works also with recreate, but Xiaomi shows a warning when debugging)

Comment: I got same error on Xiaomi Redmi 9 but I don't know what causes the error if you know something let me know thank you